# npm update only changed dependencies of a dependency

Tags: node.js, npm, lerna

Is there a way to update dependencies of a dependency A (without reinstalling the dependency A package)?

I'm trying to create a faster workflow and have a script that copies over all of the `dist/` folder and `package.json` file of some packages I'm working on to an example project for end to end testing, however that script does not update any nested dependencies and I'm looking for a way to update those.

I've tried solutions like 'verdaccio' but I'm looking to speed things up a lot but not uploading and reinstalling the whole group of packages every time I want to test something.

Comment: `rm -rf ./node_modules && npm i --production` inside the package would probably work.

Comment: hmm, probably would, but I'd like to avoid reinstalling all the dependency's dependencies if possible.  The purpose here is to speed up development.

Comment: The question says the opposite, *Is there a way to reinstall dependencies of a dependency A (without reinstalling the dependency A package)*. `rm -rf ./node_modules && npm i --production` is supposed to run inside package A.

Comment: you're right, the question and explanation did not fully match.  I suppose this would work with just going into the package and running npm install again

Comment: edited title to reflect content of question